# Focus the camera in the center of an object in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm loading and object with the ColladaLoader in three.js, so I have an bunch objects in the scene. Some of them are regular shapes such as: cubes, spheres, etc. and for these ones I can do this:

```
var position = { 
  x: selectedObject.position.x, 
  y: selectedObject.position.y, 
  z: selectedObject.position.z 
};

controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(position);
```

Where controls are the OrbitControls for the camera. The camera gets centered in that position and works fine, the problem is when the objects are not regular shapes, but geometries generated by vertices. In this case, I already tried 4 different approaches without the expected result.

1.

```
var position = { 
  x: selectedObject.matrixWorld.getPosition().x, 
  y: selectedObject.matrixWorld.getPosition().y, 
  z: selectedObject.matrixWorld.getPosition().z 
};
```

2.

```
var centerX = selectedObject.geometry.boundingSphere.center.x;
var centerY = selectedObject.geometry.boundingSphere.center.y;
var centerZ = selectedObject.geometry.boundingSphere.center.z;

var position = { x: centerX, y: centerY, z: centerZ };
```

3.

```
getCentroid(selectedObject.geometry.vertices);

function getCentroid(vertices) {
  var x = y = z = 0;
  vertices.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
    x += element.x;
    y += element.y;
    z += element.z;
  });

  return new THREE.Vector3(
    x / (vertices.length),
    y / (vertices.length),
    z / (vertices.length)
  );
}
```

4.

```
var position = getCenter(
  getMaxnMinCenter(selectedObject.geometry.vertices), 
  selectedObject.matrixWorld
);


function getMaxnMinCenter(vertices) {
  var maxX = maxY = maxZ = vertices[0];
  var minX = minY = minZ = vertices[0];

  vertices.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
    if (element.x <= minX.x) {
      minX = element;
    }
    if (element.y <= minY.y) {
      minY = element;
    }
    if (element.z <= minZ.z) {
      minZ = element;
    }
    if (element.x > maxX.x) {
      maxX = element;
    }
    if (element.y > maxY.y) {
      maxY = element;
    }
    if (element.z > maxZ.z) {
      minZ = element;
    }
  });

  return {
    minimumX: minX,
    minimumY: minY,
    minimumZ: minZ,
    maximumX: maxX,
    maximumY: maxY,
    maximumZ: maxZ,
  }
}
```

It is important to notice that regular shapes use a scale of 1.0 while the other objects use a scale of 0.005.

Thank you.

Comment: 1. `Vector3` does not take a constructor argument that is a custom object of your type. 2. You should avoid `new` and use `controls.target.set()` or `controls.target.copy()` anyway. 3. What is your question?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question is if is there anything that I am missing to get these objects centered? I mean, I guess I am getting the wrong position of the object, because when I pass it to controls.target the camera is not centered, but it moves a bit to the right, left, up, or down. Should I take the scale of the object into the equation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var bb = new THREE.Box3()
bb.setFromObject(selectedObject);
bb.center(controls.target);
```

use a boundingbox to find the center of object

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
controls.target.copy( selectedObject.position );
```

Comment: I very much appreciate you answer, but this doesn't solve my issue. Let me explain you why, I imported an object using the ColladaLoader and I also added to scene 5 meshes such us: THREE.BoxGeometry, THREE.CylinderGeometry etc. Using:

controls.target.copy( selectedObject.position );

Works for them, but the object that was imported with the ColladaLoader has some children when I do selectedObject.position for all of those children I got (0, 0, 0). So that's why I tried looking for the center of the object using the selectedObject.geometry.vertices to do the math, but it doesn't seem right.